# How to specify @Document's index name from the value of document's field itself that going to be indexed

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-annotations, spring-data-elasticsearch

Let's suppose I have two classes named `Standard` and `Student`. An instance of `Student` class “has a” reference to an instance of `Standard`. `Student` has a dependency of `Standard`.

```
public class Student{
 @id
 private String id;
 private String name;
 private Standard standard;
}

public class Standard{
 @Data
 @id
 private String id;
}
```

Now I need to index object `Student` in such way that index-name of `Student` should be Standard.getId().

```
@Document(indexName = ${Standard.getId()}, type = "section", shards = 1, replicas = 0)
public class Student{
 @id
 private String id;
 private String name;
 private Standard standard;
}

public class Standard{
 @Data
 @id
 private String id;
}
```

`Standard` is like a unique identifier that groups all the similar @Students who are reading in that Standard. Please advise whether it's possible to declare a document name at run-time which is nothing but the field of that document itself.

When I will search any student's name in that standard index it will search with in that index-name only many.The same Name of student can be reading in multiple standard\classes.

Updated: **What is my purpose?**

**I am doing this because to limit the search and to get the fast search. If I have only one index for the Student in the school and I am searching for particular student by name and standard/class then It may take a very long time to respond. Therefore I would like to create an index at the Standard level so search will be fast. Practically, It will be more easy to search a student in the class rather then in whole School level . Please correct me if I am wrong.**

Comment: Your solution seems odd to me. Why would you like to define an index per Standard-id in the first place? What is your purpose?

By using just one single index, it is for instance possible to retrieve all Students that are reading in a particular Standard. It is also possible to add the student's name to that query. Is that what you want?

Comment: @Neman I am doing this because to limit the search and to get the fast search. If I have only one index for the Student in the school and I am searching for particular student by name and standard/class then It may take a very long time to respond. Therefore I would like to create an index at the Standard level so search will be fast. Practically, It will be more easy to search a student in the class rather then in whole School level  . Please correct me if I am wrong. Thank you.

Comment: Hello. I would use a single index. This kind of stuff is what ElasticSearch is made for, just use the `Standard.id` as a filter instead of a normal search term for better performance and not affecting the score. Even with millions of students I see no problem with a single index..